# Positive edge reset and negative edge reset

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am new to Verilog and I am trying to implement an asynchronous reset.

I have difficulties understanding the difference between using `always @ (posedge clk or posedge reset)`  and `always @ (posedge clk or negedge reset)`.

What are the differences between them and which one should I use to implement the asynchronous reset?

Comment: Is your reset active-high or active-low? Think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Posedge reset` reacts on positive edge of reset signal, that is transition from  `0` to `1`. `Negedge` is transition from `1` to `0`.

Which to use depends on whether the reset signal is active high or low. If it is active high (`reset=1` means it should reset), you need to react on change from `0` to `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much. My implementation is using active high so I will use `posedge reset`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the source of your confusion is that in real life, the async reset input to a flip-flop is not actually edge-triggered, but level-triggered. (The reset happens continuously whenever the reset is active, not just at the edge.) So, the standard way of modeling flip-flops with async reset in Verilog is arguably not very precise. For completeness, here is the full implementation of a flip-flop with active high- and active low async reset, respectively:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset)
        my_flop <= 1'b0;
    else
        my_flop <= my_flop_d;
end

always @(posedge clk or negedge resetn) begin
    if (!resetn)
        my_flop <= 1'b0;
    else
        my_flop <= my_flop_d;
end
```

Note that you can drive multiple signals inside one always-block, however:

- Make sure to write all signals in both the if-reset branch and else branch. If you want to have a combination of flops with and without reset, you need multiple always-blocks. (If you write a signal in the else-branch only, `reset` will become a clock-enable for that flop, which is undesirable.)
- Do not put any code outside of the if-reset branch and else branch, e.g., above `if (reset)`. (If you do, `reset` will become part of the clock input to that flop, which is undesirable.)